# Query doesn't run when using Context supplied by Unity IoC

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework

Behold incredible wiredness....

Here's my query....

```
    var searchParams = new SearchParameters {FirstName = "Ian"};

    var query =
        Context.Prospects
            .Where(p =>
                p.ProspectId == searchParams.ProspectId
                || p.Contact.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(searchParams.FirstName.ToLower())
                || p.Contact.LastName.ToLower().Contains(searchParams.LastName.ToLower())
                || p.Contact.PhoneNumber.Contains(searchParams.PhoneNumber))
            .Join(Context.ProspectEvents, p => p.ProspectId, pe => pe.ProspectId,
                (p, pe) => new {Prospect = p, ProspectEvent = pe})
            .Join(Context.Lookup_Event, p => p.ProspectEvent.EventId, e => e.EventId,
                (p, e) => new {p.Prospect, p.ProspectEvent, Event = e})
            .Where(
                x =>
                    x.ProspectEvent.Date ==
                    Context.ProspectEvents.Where(pe => pe.ProspectId == x.Prospect.ProspectId)
                        .Max(pe => pe.Date)
            ).ToList();
```

This query is running against SQL Server 2000. I'm not sure how this could make a difference but I didn't have a problem running against 2012.

The last 'where' clause doesn't run when the EF context is provided by Unity IoC!

The error is...

> Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this

If I 'new' up a context just before the query then it works.

Any ideas??

Comment: Post your IOC container code and bootstrap

Comment: The context wasnt registered with the correct parameters. Unity does strange things when there are constructor overloads. OR create Instance externally and add Instance to IoC  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660882(v=pandp.20).aspx